# How do I get Firefox to return to the previous tab when closing a tab?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

In Opera, when closing a tab, focus returns to the most recently used tab, while in firefox, it returns focus to the right-most tab. I find that the Opera behaviour is almost always what I want. Is there anyway to get this behaviour in Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use add-on Tab Mix Plus
It will do this and much more.