# How do I set Firefox to go to the previous tab rather than the next, when a tab is closed - without using heavy addons like TMP?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

(This might be similar to [How do I get Firefox to return to the previous tab when closing a tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/136694/how-do-i-get-firefox-to-return-to-the-previous-tab-when-closing-a-tab) [at least if I'm interpreting that one right], but the accepted and only answer there - adding a big addon like TabMixPlus for this one feature - is unacceptable to me.)

When I close a tab in Firefox, it automatically goes to the next tab in list - if I have tabs A, B and C, and I close B, Firefox goes to tab C, whereas I want it the behaviour of going to tab A instead. Is there an option or an about:config variable or perhaps some tiny little addon to achieve this?

Comment: I thought Firefox went to the last active tab, which may be the next one in your case.

Comment: @MC10 I tried it out several times now, with the "last active tab" being different from the orderwise-next tab, and in each case the focus went to the next tab rather than the last-active one. Is there a setting that could be making it behave this way, any idea?

Comment: All `about:config` entries are here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries I did a Ctrl+F for tab but I don't think there's anything specifically about closing tabs. There used to be `browser.tabs.selectOwnerOnClose` but it is no longer used.

Comment: Yeah, I tried wildcard searches `tab*close` and `close*tab` in the about:config itself, and nothing relevant to this was apparent among the results. I was just hoping it was some unobvious setting that needed tweaking.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [How do I get Firefox to return to the previous tab when closing a tab?](http://superuser.com/q/136694/10259). The only answer in the original question being unacceptable to you doesn't make this question not a duplicate. You are asking essentially the same thing.

Comment: @galacticninja 1. - first of all, this question *is* arguably different from the previous one, in that it contains the implicit request for a low-memory footprint solution, which is a constraint not present in the original; that this constraint is implicit (but present in **both** the paragraphs of the question's content) doesn't mean it's not present. 2. - let's say this question *was* an exact duplicate; what purpose does marking as duplicate and closing it (which it usually leads to) serve, other than blocking potential new solutions? Link to the other one is already in the question, and...

Comment: the message "This question may already have an answer here:" is - as the question mentions - not true. It seems to follow only from blind rule allegiance. Speaking of which: 3. - according to [this FAQ answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/131904), "The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers", and this one has a more comprehensive answer that's a superset of the other one - so even going strictly by rules, that one should be the one to be marked duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get Firefox to return to the previous tab when closing a tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/136694/how-do-i-get-firefox-to-return-to-the-previous-tab-when-closing-a-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this matter some time last year and I couldn't find a built-in solution or `about:config` entry for this "problem". Thus, the answer to your question is no - there currently is no way to achieve this without installing an addon.

If you're willing to install lightweight addons, you can give [FLST (Firefox 29+)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flst-firefox-29-plus/) or [Tab Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-control/) a spin. FLST will always select the **last active** tab while Tab Control offers to always select the **left tab**. If you want more control you'll probably have to use a heavier addon like [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) which will allow you to finetune the behavior by offering a couple of options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I'll go with Tab Control for my usecase. I think I have already enabled every other option in Tab Control with default Firefox config itself, so it appears this is the only one there without an internal way of changing the configuration. Oh well.